# It is possible to make MatVerticalStepper to show the content of completed step (in a different form) with Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

By default MatVerticalStepper is hiding the content of completed step when moves to the next.
Demo: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Is it possible, instead of hiding it all together, presenting the content of completed step in a different form perhaps?